# Transfinite recursion and the cardinality of Borel sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, borel-sets, transfinite-induction

Am doing an exercise on the cardinality of Borel sets where we have and arbitrary set $X$ and the set of countable ordinals $\Omega$. Given $\mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{P}(X) $ with $\emptyset\in \mathcal{E}$ we define a collection of subsets of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as follows:

Define $\mathcal{E}^c:=\{E^c:E\in\mathcal{E}\}$  and $\mathcal{E}_{\sigma}:=\{\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n:(E_n)\subset\mathcal{E}\}$. Define $\mathcal{F}_1=\mathcal{E}\cup \mathcal{E}^c$. If $x\in\Omega$ and if $x$ has an immediate predecessor $y$ then we set $\mathcal{F}_x:=(\mathcal{F}_y)_{\sigma}\cup ((\mathcal{F}_y)_{\sigma})^c$, and if $x$ has no immediate predecessor then we set $\mathcal{F}_x:=\cup_{y<x}\mathcal{F_y}$.

Am trying to understand why this definition makes sense. I believe it is an application of the principle of recursive definition that appears on page 70 of Munkres' book:

**Theorem.** Let $J$ be a well ordered set and let $C$ be a set. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of all functions mapping sections of $J$ into $C$. Given a function $\rho:\mathcal{G}\to C$, there exists a unique function $h:J\to C$ such that $h(\alpha)=\rho(h\mid S_{\alpha})$ for each $\alpha\in J$.

If I let $J=\Omega$, $C=\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ and given $f:S_x\to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ with $S_x=\{z\in \Omega:z<x\} $ define

$$
    \rho(f) =
    \begin{cases}
      (f(y))_{\sigma}\cup ((f(y))_{\sigma})^c & \text{if $x$ has immediate predecesor $y$} \in S_x  \\
      \cup_{y<x} f(y)       & \text{if $x$ has no immediate predecesor and $x\neq \min \Omega$} \\ 
\mathcal{E}\cup \mathcal{E}^c &  \text{if $x= \min \Omega$} \end{cases}
$$

then I can invoke the above Theorem to obtain a function $h:\Omega\to \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ with $\mathcal{F}_x:=h(x)$ that satisfies

$h(1)=\rho(h\mid S_{1})=\rho(\emptyset)=\rho(S_1)=\mathcal{E}\cup \mathcal{E}^c$,

$h(x)=\rho(h\mid S_{x})=(\mathcal{F}_y)_{\sigma}\cup
((\mathcal{F}_y)_{\sigma})^c$ if $x$ has no immediate predecesor, and

$h(x)=\rho(h\mid S_{x})=\cup_{y<x} \mathcal{F}_y$ if $x$ has no immediate predecesor and $x\neq \min \Omega$.

Is this correct? Any feedback is very apprciated.

Comment: Yes, it’s correct, except that you want $\mathcal{E}\color{red}{\cup}\mathcal{E}^c$ in the last line of the definition of $\rho$, and the smallest countable ordinal is $0$, not $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I corrected the typo. For some reason my notes defined $1:=\min \Omega$ instead of $0$.

Comment: You’re very welcome. I’ve seen that convention for $\min\Omega$ before, but it always looks very strange to me (and probably to most people with a reasonably strong background in set theory).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you have time I posted a related  proof question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4118622/522332. Should be quick to verify. Any feedback is very appreciated.